# Point of inflection and third derivative

Tags: derivatives

In my textbook there is a confusing statement.
If $f'''(ξ)=0 $ and $f''(ξ)\ne0$ then $ξ$ is inflection point.  However this confuses me as it is contrary to book example and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_derivative_test).
Also in class notes it is the same as far as I can see but shouldnt derivatives be in different order? Second first and then third.

Comment: I think your textbook is just wrong, or at best is indulging in a deviant definition of inflection point. [The Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) (*not* the one you refer to) gives the conventional view.

Comment: Well what has confused me in first place was its example where it finds f''(2)=0 for a point so they check the third f'''(2)=6 and since its !=0 it states that it is a inflection point . But this doesnt have any relation with the statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must be $$f''(\xi)=0$$ and $$f'''(\xi)\ne 0$$ or higher derivatives of odd degree.

Comment: So are you 100% sure that book is wrong?

Comment: Taking the example of $f(x) = x^2$ at the origin, which is not an inflection point, but has $f''(0) \ne 0$ and $f'''(0) = 0$, I'm 100% certain that the book is wrong.